# Owner of Azure resource group cannot create resources

Tags: azure

A client of mine created a resource group in Azure. He made me an owner on the resource group but if I try to create database, function app, service app or any other resource it indicates I have insufficient permissions.  He is willing to give me the access I need, but I can't figure out what needs to be changed.

Comment: Could you please give more details and any error message or screenshot? A resource group owner can create any Azure resource within the  assigned resource group. If you cannot create resource, please double check again if you are granted to wrong resource group or subscription. Note that you don't need to be an owner of subscription.

Comment: I went back to get screen shots and now it isn't stopping me from making changes or additions to any resources.  I checked with the client and he says nothing changed.  I guess I will just have to monitor this for now.

Comment: If you haven't referred, refer the below article to give access Control  to your Azure subscription resources :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure

Comment: In the resource group, I am sure you have permission to create these resources.

Answer (score 1):

As I felt into the same issue maybe it can still help someone. [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43987308/4885217) and this [MSDN blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azure4fun/2016/10/20/common-problem-when-using-azure-resource-groups-rbac/) can be handy.